# Classic asp doesnt pick up form value i altered with JS

Tags: javascript, vbscript, asp-classic

Trying to pass a variable from JS to Classic asp. I m using a simple JS script to update the value of a form field and then trying to pick that up with Classic asp. Here is my code

PAGE1

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function GetID()
{
var url = window.location.href;
document.forms[0].getid.value = url;
}
window.onload = GetID;
// -->
</script>
.......

<form>
<input name="getid" id="getid" value="" />
</form>
```

PAGE2

```
<%dim user 
user = Request.form("getid")%>
<p>ID:<%=user%></p>
```

Any idea why that wouldn't work?

Comment: Without a specified `action` attribute, the form will always submit back to the same page ("PAGE1") and not to your "PAGE2".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to submit the form:

```
function GetID()
{
    var url = window.location.href;
    var oForm = document.forms[0];
    oForm.getid.value = url;
    oForm.action = "Page2.asp";
    oForm.submit();
}
```

Comment: Yep that works I can use the Form.submit(); command with onclick or with onrefresh.
Thanks guys great answers!

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things I could suggest here...

1. Try setting your `form` method...

   ```html
   <form method="post">...</form>
   ```
2. Make sure you're actually identifying the control that the `var url` is pointing at; may be safer to use `document.getElementById("...")`:

   ```
   document.getElementById("getid").value = url;
   ```

These may work but let me know if not...

-- EDIT --

More...

You could use a Microsoft `XMLHTTP` object to pass the data across if you like (very much like AJAX)...

```js
/*
    AJAX extension to allow dynamic interaction between pages.

    This section initialises the variable used to store the XMLHTTP request object.
*/
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari...
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else {
    // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

/*
    ajaxPage
        Posts a request to the scripted specified page.
    Parameters:
        postPage (string) - The page to be opened.
        paramList (string) - The list of parameters/values to be applied to the page.
    Usage:
        var targetBlock = document.getElementById("resultDiv");
        targetBlock.innerHTML = ajaxPage("resultsPage.asp","calcVal=545")
    Description:
        This routine uses the xmlhttp requesting tools within JavaScript to act as an intermediary between
        script and page.  Specify all paramters in the paramList by separating with an ampersand (&).
*/
function ajaxPage(postPage, paramList) {
    xmlhttp.open("POST",postPage,false);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send(paramList);
    return xmlhttp.responseText;
}
```

Comment: That's good advice actually but what I figured out is the function doesn't work unless you re using the form's submit button. (which id rather not) I can convert the button as an image and make due but I wonder if there's a way around it

Comment: @vast365 - Classic ASP is server side code, so you'll need to submit your form somehow whether it is via a submit button or some sort of AJAX function behind the scenes

Comment: Cheers Westie nice suggestions (+1ed)

Answer (score -1):

-- DISREGARD THIS POST, see Shadow Wizard's comment --
@vast365, this is failing because in your `window.onload` you need the parenthesis to *execute* the function, like `window.onload = GetID();` otherwise you're telling javascript to set the target var (in this case your field's value) to the definition of your function GetID.  You can see this demonstrated in my fiddle as I move the definition to the `foo` variable, and then executing `foo()`: http://jsfiddle.net/jb_pcs/DPaYt/

So what you want simply is:  http://jsfiddle.net/jb_pcs/DPaYt/1/

PS - this has **nothing** to do with your ASP code. :)
PPS - you can always alert your new field value before posting the page to ASP, like so: http://jsfiddle.net/jb_pcs/DPaYt/2/

Cheers!

Comment: This is plain wrong. `window.onload = GetID()` will execute the function instantly and only assign *its return value* as the onload event. [Proof](http://jsfiddle.net/DPaYt/3/), check the console and see the error. `window.onload = GetID;` is the correct way to assign a function as event handler.